# Can you use LiveSDK from Console Application?

Tags: c#, live-sdk

I'm trying to make a console application which accesses my SkyDrive account, however I cannot figure out how to get the Live SDK working.

I'm running on Live SDK version 5.4 and this is the code I'm trying to run - the loginResult.Status is always "Unknown":

```
private static async Task<LiveConnectClient> ConnectToLive()
{
    LiveAuthClient authClient = new LiveAuthClient("my live ID");

    var loginResult = await authClient.IntializeAsync(new[] { "wl.basic" });
    if (loginResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
        return new LiveConnectClient(loginResult.Session);
    return null;
}
```

A few things I'm not certain about (since the SDK documentation is somewhat lackluster at best):

1. "My live ID" - is this just my e-mail address used for my personal Live account, or is it some sort of application specific ID that you have to create somewhere ?
2. Is InitializeAsync the proper method to call for authenticating ? All examples I've found mention a "LoginAsync", but that method is not available in the DLL.
3. Is it even possible to use the SDK outside of Windows Phone / Metro apps ?

Comment: Hi Steffen,
Did you find an answer to this, as I have same question?
The examples in the LiveSDK show how to get a ClientID, and with that you can run the example (for me it as the Desktop ApiExplorer). But the login pops up a login window

Answer (score 0):

I got the following code to work using a SkyDriveClient downloaded from http://skydriveapiclient.codeplex.com/releases/view/103081

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new SkyDriveServiceClient();

        client.LogOn("YourEmail@hotmail.com", "password");
        WebFolderInfo wfInfo = new WebFolderInfo();

        WebFolderInfo[] wfInfoArray = client.ListRootWebFolders();

        wfInfo = wfInfoArray[0];
        client.Timeout = 1000000000;

        string fn = @"test.txt";
        if (File.Exists(fn))
        {
            client.UploadWebFile(fn, wfInfo);
        }

    }
```